# Failure to burn DVD in the Nero applications

Tags: dvd-burning, nero

I'm having a problem, about the dvd-rw. Been a long time I did not use the DVD, but lately I am so use it. But there is a problem. Initially I was using an application that is nero v7, after a 1% start burning, it suddenly failed ... I think it's because the crash nero apps, then I update the nero v9. I even change its dvd-rw. But still the same warning appears, and all failed due to "invalid block address".

appear warnings, logs as below:

```
Recorder: <PIONEER DVD-RW DVR-112D> Version: 1.06 - HA 1 TA 0 - 9.0.9.100 
Adapter driver: <IDE> HA 1 
Drive buffer : 2000kB 
Bus Type : default CD-ROM: <PIPCR LYNG5EFKPA >
Version: 1.03 - HA 1 TA 1 - 9.0.9.100 
Adapter driver: <IDE> HA 1
```

Does anyone know what the solution should I do? Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell which anti virus do you use?

Comment: I use avira anti virus. Does it influence?

Comment: No now I'm going to post an answer regarding this because many users have this issue due to Kaspersky.

Comment: Is it windows XP or 7?

Comment: Kaspersky? Do you can post your answer about it. My operation system is windows XP.

Comment: I posted it, yes kaspersky AV making a mess with the burning process so it would be worth to give a try with disable the protection of Avira AV. Also give a try to those tools which I mentioned in answer. And its `Operating System` not `Operation`. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can try to burn the DVD with DMA disabled. Right click on the `My Computer` icon and select `Device Manager` or press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `Devmgmt.msc` and uncheck

`Device Manager>IDE Channel Properties>Advanced Settings>Enable DMA`

If this doesn't help, you can try to disable the antivirus or to use other tools to burn the DVD like [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/?page_id=5) and [Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download), which are both free and can burn the image.

Comment: I am a little confused with the existing measures. 
For the latter. Now I'll try it. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: What is the confusion you can ask freely?

Comment: Apparently it is listed on the first step, I have done. Previously I've done 'Enable DMA'. But it seems I do not feel the changes. But I do not know well.

Comment: You can't see the changes because these are not view able. It will effect the memory as DMA stands for direct memory access so the nero will work pretty slow now rather than fast.